# Can an NHibernate session have two data readers open in separate threads?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'd like to know the correct approach for running two simultaneous queries using NHibernate.  Right now, I have a single `ISession` object that I use for all my queries:

```
session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
```

In one thread, I'm loading some data which takes 10-15 seconds, but I don't need it right away so I don't want to block the entire program while it's loading:

```
IDbCommand cmd = session.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
cmd.CommandText = "RecipesForModelingGraph";
IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
   // Do stuff
}

reader.Close();
```

This works fine, however in another thread I might be running a query such as:

```
var newBlah = new Blah();
session.Save(newBlah);
```

When the above transaction commits, I occasionally get an exception:

> Additional information: There is already an open DataReader associated
>   with this Command which must be closed first.

Now, I thought maybe this was because I was running everything in the same transaction.  So, I surrounded all my loading code with:

```
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
{
   // Same DataReader code as above
}
```

However, the problem has not gone away.  I'm thinking maybe I need *each thread* to have its own `ISession` object.  Is this the correct approach, or am I doing something wrong.  Note, I only want a single open connection to the database.  Also, keep in mind the background thread is only *loading* data and nothing else, so I'm not worried about isolation levels and data changing as its being read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session is tied to the thread and the Commands created are linked to the sessions connection object.  So yes, if a commit or close is executed while an open reader exists you will get an exception.

You could Join() your threads and wait until all are complete before closing/committing.

Comment: I don't want the rest of my program blocked while the background thread is loading data though, so I can't `Join()`.  If I call `OpenSession()` again, is that going to create a new connection to the database?  I guess that might be fine, as this *loading* thread only lives for about 10-15 seconds, so I could just close the session when the thread exits.

Comment: would calling Join() block other calls?  I don't see that but don't have big picture.  Yeah, calling OpenSession() is probably a cleaner approach.

Comment: Ok, either way sounds like sessions aren't meant to be shared across threads.  So, my design is incorrect and needs to be fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: remember, the NEW thread needs to create the new session, I assume you know that.